# Access Violation When Writing Dynamic 2D Array... Sometimes

Tags: c++, access-violation, dynamic-arrays

This program is meant to generate a dynamic array, however it gives an access violation error when writing when given certain dimensions. Eg: R = 6, C = 5 crashes, but then R = 5, C = 6 doesn't. In case your wondering, it isn't my homework to "fix" this broken program, this is the method we were taught in class. Also part of my assessment is to use this method, so vectors are out. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

const int R = 6;
const int C = 5;

char **d;

d = new char *[R];

for(int i=0; i<C; ++i){
    d[i] = new char[C];
}

//initialise
for(int i=0; i<R; ++i){
    for(int j=0; j<C; ++j){
        d[i][j] = 'd';
        cout<<d[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
cout<<endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even though writing `d[r][c]` might look nice, all those `new` calls might become tedious for much larger values of R. I would therefore give `char *d = new char[C*R]; for (...) d[r*C+c] = 'd';` a serious thought. Possibly rounding up `C` to the next power of 2, if the target machine has really slow multiplications.

Comment: Even though you can access it with the `d[][]` notation, this structure is *not* a 2d array. When you write `char e[R][C];` you get *one* block of memory totaling `R*C*sizeof(char)`. With the structure that you are using (sometimes called a "ragged array") you get one allocation of `R*sizeof(char*)` plus `R` allocations of `C*sizeof(char)` (which may or may not be contiguous (or even distinct!)) nor is there actually any need for each row to be the same length. Different things.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @ndim, yer I tried that way first but couldn't figure out access, for the moment this should be fine as R and C won't go above 10.

@dmckee, thanks for clarifying, a little over my head, but I'm sure it will make sense in time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<C; ++i){
    d[i] = new char[C];
}
```

should be

```
for(int i=0; i<R; ++i){
    d[i] = new char[C];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first loop creates a new `char` array for elements of the `d` array between `0` and `C-1` inclusively.

The second outer loop goes from `0` to `R-1` inclusively. So the last `d[i]` accessed is not initialized. This will typically fail.

To solve the problem, use that as your first loop

```
for(int i=0; i<R; ++i){
    d[i] = new char[C];
}
```